# How to open a URL from a Listbox in Tkinter TTK

Tags: python, tkinter, url, listbox

I am trying to open URLs based on choices from a set of list boxes. I have the listboxes showing the options successfully. But when I try and double-click the URL to open the browser, I get a traceback saying:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: links() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
`#List Boxes
box01 = Listbox(my_frame, width=23)
box02 = Listbox(my_frame)
box03 = Listbox(my_frame, width=len_max)
box04 = Listbox(my_frame)
box01.grid(row=0, column=0)
box02.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20)
box03.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20)
box04.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=20)

#items in list one

for item in solutions:
    box01.insert(END, item)

#Bind the Listbox
box01.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", product)
box02.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", category)
box03.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", article)
box04.bind("<Double-1>", links)

def links():
    weblink = box04.get(ANCHOR)
    webbrowser.open_new(weblink)

links = [
    "www.google.com"
]`
```

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

I have tried several solutions on this site but none have gotten me any closer to resolving this issue. I appreciate any insight.

Comment: Function for an event binding expects an argument, the event object.  So `links()` should be defined to accept an argument.

Comment: Thank you so much! setting the def Links(e) fixed the issue.